# How do I remove texture from an object in illustrator cs6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, texture

I created a logo with some wooden texture in it. I'd like to get rid of the texture and fill it with a different color. I'm not sure what to do. I am able to change the color but the texture remains.

Comment: Can you post the logo?

Comment: Hey Jen! At Matt said, we need more information to help you. It seems this is a pattern with your questions; if you [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner) I think we can lead you in the right direction and give some pointers on how to ask questions that we're capable of answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely wild guess......

Select the object with the texture. Look in the Appearance Panel (`Window > Appearance`) and if there's an effect located there, drag it to the small trash can on the bottom of the Appearance Panel.